# Login with Node and React

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, fetch

I'm creating a very simple login with React and Node as part of an assignment at school, no authentication needed.
This is my code:

**Server.js**

```
app.post('/auth', function (request, response) {
   var username = request.body.username;
   var password = request.body.password;
   
   if (username && password) {
      response.redirect('/home');
   } else {
      response.send('Please enter Username and Password!');
      response.end();
   }
});
```

and this is my front end

**Loggin.js**

```
handleLogin = () => {
   const { username, password } = this.state;

   const requestOptions = {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
      body: JSON.stringify({
         user: {
            username: username,
            password: password
         }
      })
   };

   fetch('http://localhost:8080/auth', requestOptions)
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(data => {
         console.log(data.success)
         if (data.success) {
            window.location = "/home";
         }
      });
}
```

But is not working. When I console.log username and password it says **undefined**

I have been trying to find a solution before to post here but I can not find it, and I do not know what am I doing wrong.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the frontend sends a body of type:

```
body = {
    user: {
        username: 'value',
        password: 'value'
    }
}
```

but on the backend you read `username` and `password` directly from the `body` object. Either update your backend logic to:

```
app.post('/auth', function(request, response) {
   var username = request.body.user.username;
   var password = request.body.user.password;

   if (username && password) {
           response.redirect('/home');
   } else {
       response.send('Please enter Username and Password!');
       response.end();
   }
});
```

or your frontend one to:

```
body: JSON.stringify({
     username: username,
     password: password
});
```

Comment: Thank you so much! it fixed my problem. I did not check that.

Answer (score 1):

Your react application expects a JSON answer but receives a plain text.
try something like

```
 response.json({error: 'Please enter Username and Password!'});
```

Comment: Thanks, I tried but is like POST is not working, because when console.log user and password they are empty.